# VBScript check if key combo pressed

Tags: windows, script, vbscript

How can I make a script that waits in a while loop for a specific keyboard combination before doing something? I want to run the script and then have it wait for ALT+CTRL+Q and then execute the rest of the script.

I've searched around but finding VBScript info is kinda hard.  The ones I do find seem to be Internet Explorer related.

Comment: is this a standalone script,part of a Office app?  If standalone,  you may be out of luck but look at the Read method for StdIn

Comment: @uSlackr Standalone I guess? I'm trying to control some windows operations with a script like opening a program, running some commands in the program then closing the program.

Comment: Look into AutoIt or AutoHotKey, you'll be able to find more for detecting keypresses than with VBScript. They also have built ins for automating windows and controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will wait for the ENTER key:

```
strMessage = "Press the ENTER key to continue."
Wscript.StdOut.Write strMessage

Do While Not WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfLine
   Input = WScript.StdIn.Read(1)
Loop
WScript.Echo "The script is complete."
```

You may be able to check what value `Input` is getting to see if your desired keypress has a value you can test for

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to look into keyboard hooks. You may be somewhat limited in only having VBScript to play with.

Check out:

http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Code/Libraries/Hooks/Journal_Record_Hooks/article.asp